# Why constructor returns nothing ? or it returns something?

Tags: java, constructor

I read in many java books that constructor have no returns type , it means that it does not return anything ? is it really happen ? or it may return something ?
I want to know the reason.

Please anyone give me the technical reason.

Comment: It **do not** return anything.

Comment: [Related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509968/what-is-constructor-in-java-if-it-is-not-a-member-of-class).

Comment: In theory, the constructor does not return anything but simply modifies the object that will be returned by the `new` operation.  In practice, it wouldn't work for you to return anything other than `this` anyway, so the return value would be redundant.

Answer (score 2):

> I read in many java books that constructor have no returns type , it means that it does not return anything ?

Yes, its return type is `V` for void.

> is it really happen ?

Yes.

> or it may return something ?

No.

> I want to know the reason.

The question shouldn't be; Why not?,

The question should be; Do I really have?  and the answer is no.

Comment: Someone think that we both sit in same room :P

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ My long lost twin brother ;)

Comment: Is it true that constructor has `void` return type?

Comment: @Aniket at the JVM level, yes. Not from a Java point of view.

Comment: @Aniket The default constructor for a class will be called `<init>()V` where `V` is the return type.  Similarly the static initialiser method is called `<clinit>()V`

Answer (score 2):

> it means that it does not return anything ?

No,It won't.

> is it really happen ?

Yes It happens

> or it may return something ?

Again No,it won't return anything.

[Providing constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) is optional,the name it self indicating, it just helps in construction of the object.Wont return anything.

Comment: Thanks for answering, and I also know that...constructor don't have any return type...so it is not returning anything but I read somewhere that Constructor implicitly returns class type itself. So, is it a true statement.

Answer (score 0):

`Constructors` have one purpose  is to create an `instance` of a class.Where as The purpose of methods, by contrast, is much more general. A method's basic function is to execute Java code.So `Constructor` never returns anything where as `method` may or may not return somthing.

Answer (score 0):

While constructors technically return nothing, the `new` call creates a new skeleton object at defaults, and then calls the correct constructor(and initializer blocks).

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly it will return the object of the corresponding class. WE should not mention the return type for constructor

Answer (score 0):

A [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) is a special block of code that is called whenever a new object is created. It is called to initialize the new object.

A constructor does not return anything, and you never call a constructor directly. You use the `new` operator to create a new object. The `new` operator reserves memory for the object, then calls the constructor to initialize it, and then returns a reference to the new object.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are for initialising objects.  They do their work, and that's it - the object is initialised. Returning stuff is NOT what constructors are for.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to ([Can constructor return a null object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103444/java-can-creating-an-object-return-a-null-reference))

It is a common behavior across all OOP languages that constructors do not have a erturn type in their signature. In fact, an instance of the class type enclosing the constructor definition is returned.